# Input and Output of the Convolutional Neural Network is a 3D matrix

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, point-clouds

I am writing a code for 3D pointcloud object detection and classification. First I labeled all my raw pointcloud and now converted it to voxels so at every timestamp I get a 3D matrix with 4 features. And I expect my output to be again the same 3D matrix with labels. In programming terms:

My Input to the neural network is - [no. of entries, 4(features), 10, 20, 15].

My output from the network is [no. of entries, 1, 10, 20, 15]

and due to one hot vector my shape now is :[no. of entries, 10, 20, 15, 8] due to 8 classes.

So which layers as input and output should I use in keras so that it does not give me any error?

I use this layer as an input for the network :

```
model.add(Convolution3D(64, 3, 3, 3, activation='relu', 
                border_mode='same', name='conv1',
                subsample=(1, 1, 1), 
                input_shape=(4, 10, 20, 15)))
```

But I am not able to figure out by adding pooling layers and other layers the size is reduced. Which layer should I use as an output and how to maintain the same size in the center layers?

Comment: If you don't use pooling layers and keep the padding same in every layer, you will be able to maintain dimensions.

Comment: yes, i figured out the input and output layer but is there any way to use pool layers in between?

Comment: Pooling layers reduce the dimensions, that is there definition, choosing max/average from a pool, so no.